# How to restart a kubernetes pod when a liveness probe fails

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers running in a pod.
One of the containers have a health endpoint.
I am looking for a way to restart the main container where I can't add the endpoint when the liveness probe fails in the other container.

I think I can use the exec option in liveness probe add restart the main container.

Comment: Could you please explain more `I am looking for a way to restart the main container where I can't add the endpoint when the liveness probe fails in the other container.`? I could not understand your requirements.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  I'm not totally following the specific issue you're encountering; can you describe in a little more detail what happens when the liveness probe fails, and what you want to happen?  It's often easier to manage only one container per Pod, does splitting this into two Deployments help?